# How to pass object to an activity?

Tags: android

I have two activities, NewTransferMyOwn.java and FromAccount.java

When I go from NewTransferMyOwn.java to FromAccount.java, I do write code as following

```
Intent i = new Intent(NewTransferMyOwn.this, FromAccount.class);
startActivityForResult(i, FROM_ACCOUNT);
```

When I do come back from FromAccount.java to NewTransferMyOwn.java, then I want to pass a complete object of class **Statement**

I do write code as

```
Statement st = ItemArray.get(arg2);//ItemArray is ArrayList<Statement>, arg2 is int
Intent intent = new Intent(FromAccount.this,NewTransferMyOwn.class).putExtra("myCustomerObj",st);
```

I do get error as following on putExtra,

**Change to 'getIntExtra'**

as I do, there is again casting st to int, what is issue over here, how can I pass Statement object towards back to acitivity?

Comment: [You should do some search](http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=android+passing+my+object+to+another+activity)

Comment: I think there is something between you and  google :-P @AdilSoomro, thanks I do, but now time kam he dear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also implement your custom class by `Serializable` and pass the custom Object,

```
public class MyCustomClass implements Serializable
{
  // getter and setters
}
```

And then pass the Custom Object with the Intent.

```
intent.putExtra("myobj",customObj);
```

To retrieve your Object

```
Custom custom = (Custom) data.getSerializableExtra("myobj");
```

**UPDATE:**

To pass your custom Object to the previous Activity while you are using `startActivityForResult`

```
Intent data = new Intent();
Custom value = new Custom();
value.setName("StackOverflow");
data.putExtra("myobj", value);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

To retrieve the custom Object on the Previous Activity

```
if(requestCode == MyRequestCode){
     if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
         Custom custom = (Custom) data.getSerializableExtra("myobj");
         Log.d("My data", custom.getName()) ;
         finish();
     }
 }
```

Comment: I cannot do that because of :
"The method putExtra(String, Parcelable) is ambiguous for the type Intent"

Comment: in the previous `Activity` the result would be extracted from `Bundle` so it will be `newBundle()..getExtras().getSerializeable("key")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass arbitrary objects between activities. The only data you can pass as extras/in a bundle are either fundamental types or [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) objects.

And Parcelables are basically objects that can be serialized/deserialized to/from a string.

You can also consider passing only the URI refering to the content and re-fetching it in the other activity.

Comment: Parcelables are not serialized to strings. They are special objects that can be passed through Binder IPC. Basically your object to be passed between processes should realize Parcelable interface and should consists of basic types.