# How to pass arraylist values statically from one class to other in android?

Tags: android

I am storing my data into arraylist of one class and sending that arraylist data to other class. But the values of the arraylist are not coming to the other class. I have given like

**page1.java**

```
static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList1;
```

**page2.java**

```
static List<ArrayList<String>> mystringList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 mystringList1 = page1.stringList1;
```

Dont know where I am going wrong..but tried a lot to send the data....Please help me regarding this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it `public` `static` and you will be able to pass your `ArrayList` to Another Class. But, better way would be to use `Serializable` or `Parcelable` to pass it.

**UPDATE**

**Application Class** From the Docs.

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state.
>   You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class
>   to be instantiated for you when the process for your
>   application/package is created

Other Option is you can create a class that extends `Application` and you can use a `getter` `setter` for the `ArrayList` there in the `Application` class. `Application` Class is available to your whole Application and you can get the values everywhere using the Application Context.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response...can you give an example for that please...?

Comment: @Sweety: using Application class is also not a good solution, you should use `Parcelable ArrayList` you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7400675/593709) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8687006/593709)

Comment: @Sweety Adil has given you the Examples link fpr Serializable & Parcelable and for Application class here is the [link](http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-application-class.html).

Comment: hi thanks for your valuable suggestions...I had made a small mistake...i.e I am clearing the array in the other page..thats why I am unable to get the array data to page2 class..now it is workig fine

Answer (score 1):

you can try getter setter method for transferring values between two classes. I think that would be best for your project.

For e.g.

```
private String myValue; 

public void setValue ( String myValue )
{
     this.myValue = myValue;
}

public String getValue()
{
      return myValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help u i think.

```
**page1.java**

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringList1; 

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getstringList1()
    {
        return stringList1;
    }

**page2.java**

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mystringList1  = page1.getstringList1();
```