# How to pass complex data between Service and Activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

How do we pass complex data (say, employee Object) between a Service and Activity?

Here, the Service and Activity are in different package. May be different application.

Comment: see this one [pass object to an activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686938/how-to-pass-object-to-an-activity) .

Comment: Check this example: [Android – Send object from one activity to another Activity using Intent](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-send-object-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First serialize the object which you want to pass.
- Put the serialize object in intent extras.
- In receiving end, just get the serialized object, deserialize it.

say,

```
 Employee employee = new Employee();
```

then,

```
intent.putExtra("employee", serializeObject(employee));
```

while receiving,

```
byte[] sEmployee = extras.getByteArray("employee");
```

employee = (Employee) deserializeObject(sEmployee);

FYI,

```
public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) throws Exception,IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    try {
        out.writeObject(o);
        // Get the bytes of the serialized object
        byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

        return buf;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "serializeObject", e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}

public static Object deserializeObject(byte[] b)
        throws StreamCorruptedException, IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException, Exception {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
    try {
        Object object = in.readObject();
        return object;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "deserializeObject", e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your complex data typed object (e.g. Employee) by either implementing **Parcelable** or **Serializable** interface.

Then create Intent and use **putExtra()** by passing the **parcelable** or **serializable** object into it.

Then in the target class use **getParcelableExtra()** or **getSerializableExtra()** etc to get that object.