# how to pass a user defined object from one activity to another

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

I want to pass a user defined class object from one `Activity` to another. I know the way we pass a `String` to other `Activity`:

```
Intent in=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,WebserviceClient.class);
in.putExtra("res", "abc");
startActivityForResult(in, 0);
```

and how to extract it on the other side:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
res = i.getStringExtra("res");
```

But I want to know how to do this for both sides for a user defined object?

Comment: Parcelable is the answer, see the discussion in this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363503/passing-a-custom-object-from-one-activity-to-another-parcelable-vs-bundle

Comment: I would suggest you to explore Stackoverflow before asking such repeated Questions/Answers.

Comment: Check: [**How to pass object to an activity?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686938/how-to-pass-object-to-an-activity),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your class to `Parcelable` interface.
This guide may help [Pass complex object data structure to Intent](https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/pass-complex-object-structure-to-intent/)

Answer (score 1):

Let your class implement `Parcelable` and pass it as intent extra.

Answer (score 1):

implements **Serializable** that class which class of object you want send

```
  Intent in=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,WebserviceClient.class);
                    in.putExtra("res",objectOfClass);
                    startActivityForResult(in, 0);
```

to extract other side

```
 Bundle extraData = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extraData != null) {
            objectOfClass = (Classname) extraData
                    .getSerializable("res");
        }
```

Comment: How your code differs from the one that he placed in the question? He is asking about passing a custom object not just a String

Comment: check my edited answer.its may satisfy you.

Comment: On Android, Parcelable is faster than Serializable, which is a generic Java construct, while Parcelable is an Android thing.

Answer (score 1):

you can use my class, 
to pass object to another activity you need to create parcelable object,but make  sure your bean class implements parcel here CategoryBean is my bean class

```
/**
         * A method to create pacelable{@link Parcelable} object
         * @param album
         * @return
         */
        public  ParcelHashMap parseObject(CategoryBean mCategoryBean){
            ParcelHashMap p = new ParcelHashMap();
            p.put("CategoryBean", mCategoryBean);
            return p;
        }
```

and pass it with intent, from Activity1

```
Intent in=new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
in.putExtra("myCatObject", parseObject(selectedCategoryObject));
startActivity(in);
```

and in secondActivity just pass that parcelabel object to get real object like below

```
    /**
     * To get parsed object from Parcelable object, you can use int,string or any object
     * @param parsedObje Parcelable
     * @return PhotosBean Object
     */
    public  CategoryBean parseObject(Parcelable parsedObje){
        return (CategoryBean)((ParcelHashMap)parsedObje).get("CategoryBean");
    }
```

A class for parcel

package com.ixorian;
    import java.util.HashMap;

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class ParcelHashMap implements Parcelable {
    private HashMap<String,Object> map;

    public ParcelHashMap() {
        map = new HashMap<String,Object> ();
    }

    public ParcelHashMap(Parcel in) {
        map = new HashMap<String,Object> ();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public ParcelHashMap createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ParcelHashMap(in);
        }

        public ParcelHashMap[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParcelHashMap[size];
        }
    };

//  @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

//  @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(map.size());
//      for (String s: map.keySet().toArray(new String[0])) {
//          dest.writeString(s);
//          dest.writeString((String) map.get(s));
//      }

         for (HashMap.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {  
             dest.writeString(entry.getKey());  
             dest.writeValue(entry.getValue());  
             }  
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        int count = in.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            map.put(in.readString(), in.readValue(ParcelHashMap.class.getClassLoader()));
        }
    }

    public Object get(String key) {
        return (Object) map.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, Object value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach that i follow to pass custom Objects between Andriod Activities ,is by defining a  Singleton class in my project,  that contains all the objects & variables that i need to pass around between Activities ,Suppose you want to pass a custom object from Activity A-->B , you define a Singleton class containing the object template you want to pass, you simply call a setter method in Activity A , and a getter in Activity B.