# Android Image View data?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-imageview

here i have an `Activity` in that create `ImageButton` in `XML` on that `ImageButton` arrange Two `ImageViews` and Two `TextViews` like this see click this `ImageButton` that data receive in next `Activity`.

my question is how to get all `ImageButton` data from this `Activity` to next `Activity`. Any one Have Idea give some ideas....

Comment: Explain better, please: on ImageButton click you want to collect data from the two TextViews, `sip_name` and `sip_status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of your button just put the data that you want to move into the other activity

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
    i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
    i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
    // Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the
    // callback via this code
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
  }
```

Then you can get this data into the other activity like this

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
      return;
    }
    String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
    String value2 = extras.getString("Value2");
```

This is called the explicit intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data you need in a `Bundle` and pass it in the `Intent`. If you absolutely need to pass the `Button`, try to create a class that implements `Serializable` and holds a button instance in its parameters that is instantiated to your `Button`. And use the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686938/how-to-pass-object-to-an-activity) answer to pass this `Serializable` class to the new `Activity` via the `Intent`.